# How to Make a UIButton fix at UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I am having an UIButton at my UIScrollView and when i zoom my scroll view the button position is not fix...is there any way to make it fix at one location?

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 11, `UIScrollView` has an instance property called [`frameLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2865772-framelayoutguide). `frameLayoutGuide` has the following declaration:

```
var frameLayoutGuide: UILayoutGuide { get }
```

> The layout guide based on the untransformed frame rectangle of the scroll view.

> Use this layout guide when you want to create Auto Layout constraints that explicitly involve the frame rectangle of the scroll view itself, as opposed to its content rectangle.

---

The following Swift 5.1 / iOS 13 `UIViewController` implementation shows how to use `frameLayoutGuide` in order to center a `UIButton` inside a `UIScrollView`.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "LargeImage"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set scrollView constraints
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        // Set imageView constraints
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        // Set button constraints (centered)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        scrollView.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Place/set your button over scroll view (not inside scroll view) as shown here in this snapshot. And also set button constraints (position) with respect to super view of your scrollview.

[image]

Here is ref. snapshot of hierarchy of position of each view over each-other.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your button to stay at a fixed size and position when you modify your scrollview, the best way would be to not have it be in the scrollview at all. Add the button to the parent view of the scrollview, then it won't be affected by any changes to the scrollview and can be overlaid on top of it.

Comment: is this the most simple way to do it?

Comment: Yes, this is is the most simple way of doing it by far. Otherwise, you would need to implement `scrollViewDidScroll:` to change the position of the button when the scroll view scrolls to make it appear static and `scrollViewDidZoom:` to reset the transform of the button as the scroll view zooms to make it appear to stay the same size. This is more costly and requires more work to implement. If you add the button outside if the `UIScrollView` hierarchy, no extra work is required.

Answer (score 0):

You should position your button outside the scroll view and anchor it to the bottom of the page. This way the content in your scroll view will change but your button will remain statically fixed on the view.